# Find by where NOT current row

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a small cms and I am using `spring data jpa` to do my database stuff.

When I add a new page, I want to make sure the slug doesn't already exist, for that purpose I added a method to my repository:

```
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, Integer> {

    Page findBySlug(String slug);

}
```

That works fine when adding.

However when editing a page, I want to check that the slug doesn't already exist but NOT for the current page, how can I do that? I guess I could somehow pass the current row id or something like that, but how would I do that?

Comment: you can write a custom JPQL query if you can't do it with the DSL

Comment: you want to check: SELECT * from Pages WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT slug from Pages p ) ??  So you want to check if there is any row containing the variable slug in your pages table?

Comment: I was hoping it's possible by some automagic without JPQL

Comment: Perhaps a flag field in the Page entity? editedBy? Just rambling.

Comment: If you're using `spring-data-rest`, you could do your check in a `@HandleBeforeSave` handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
Page findBySlugAndIdNot(String slug,Long id)
```

where id is name of your identifier in entity with proper type. Look at [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Answer (score 0):

you may try custom query like :

```java
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM Page p WHERE p.slug = :slug and p.pageId!=pageId")
public boolean existsBySlugInPage(@Param("slug") String slug, @Param("pageId") Integer pageId);
```